# Prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $2^n-n^2$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, exponentiation

My original question is: Find all the number $x$ such that, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, n\ge 5$, we have $ 2^n-n^2 | x^n -n^x$.

The first thing to notice is that, if $n$ is even, then $2^n-n^2$ is even and thus, $x$ must be even. So I denote $x=2k$.

Further transformations yields $2^n-n^2 | k^n -(2^{k-1})^n , \forall n \in \mathbb {N}, n \ge 5, n$ odd.

The problem will be completed if I have the following statement:

> **There are infinitely many primes of the form $2^n-n^2$**

Any help for either of the problem is appreciated!

Comment: We do not even know if the set of primes of the form $n^2+1$ is infinite.

Comment: The set of $n$ such that $2^n-n^2$ is prime for $5\leq n\leq 2000$ is [ 5, 7, 9, 17, 19, 51, 53, 81, 83, 119, 189, 219, 227, 301, 455, 461, 623 ]. But I think you might have turned an easier question into an incredibly hard one.

Comment: I think the answer to your question might be $x=2,4$. But I cannot prove it yet.

Comment: @DavidCraven can you help with the first question??

Comment: @NikolaTolzsek is this a problem to which the answer is expected to be known (e.g., homework), or is this an open problem? Since there are many incredibly difficult number-theory problems like this, it would be useful to know which this is.

Comment: @DavidCraven this is to be known. Like a challenge from my math teacher.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this should work for most of it. Since it's meant to be a challenge I have left one part unexplained.

I claim that x must be a power of 2. To see this, let $p$ be odd and suppose that $p\mid x$. Let $x=pk$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

[Here's the unexplained bit.] Choose $n$ so that $p\mid(2^n-n^2)$. Notice that $p\nmid n$ in this case. But $p\mid (x^n-n^x)=(p^n\cdot k^n-n^x)$. Thus $p\mid n$, a contradiction.

Hence no odd prime can divide $x$. (Notice that if $p=2$ then all this breaks down.) Note that $2$ and $4$ work. I know $8$ doesn't, but I haven't got a good proof for the rest of the powers of $2$.

Comment: This is the easy part, however I got this one completed. Thank for your help!

Comment: It was a while back, but I think I came up with a reasonable proof for the 2-power case. But was a month ago...